# sending push notification from php

Tags: php, push-notification

```
<?php

$APPLICATION_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$REST_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';

$data = array(
    'channel' => 'News',
    'type' => 'ios',
    'expiry' => 1451606400,
    'data' => array(
        'alert' => 'Test Push',
        'sound' => 'push.caf',
    ),
);
$_data = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($curl);

?>
```

I am using this script for sending push notifications. is it compulsory to mention channel?

Whenever I run this script, I am not receiving any notifications while when I send from parse site, devices are receiving notifications. Please help.

Comment: Is this supposed to send to every person on your notification list? I don't see where a recipient is defined. Do you have error display enabled / see any errors when running this script on your server? Do you see a success message from parse? Need a lot more information to help. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can use slim library for this ....check this link
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use where clause

```
$data = array(
  //'channel' => 'News',
  //'type' => 'ios',
  'where'=>'{}'
'expiry' => 1451606400,
'data' => array(
    'alert' => 'Test Push',
    'sound' => 'push.caf',
),);
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: where clause is sending message to all devices which are registered at Installation object. in this condition no comparison with any specific value. it worked for me.